# How can I use another df to calculate a new variable in my df, using time intervals?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a new variable that accounts for the in fetus exposition of pollution during pregnancy, summing the number of times each pregnant were exposed during this time.

I have one dataframe that has information about the exposition, with daily data. Each column with dummy variable is a type of exposition I want to sum up.

And another dataframe has information about the interval of pregnancy per individual.
As both datasets don't have nothing in common besides the locations' code, and they are also gigantic, I cannot join them in the regular way.

I was thinking on doing a loop over the exposition df, asking to filter the time interval I want, and then mutating the variable as I need. But my code does not work since I'm referring to two different datasets and trying to to a loop for a dataframe, which is more difficult as well. So, I don't know what I'm doing and hope you could enlighten me.

`for (row in exposition) {`
`pollution<- pollution%>%`
`group_by(code_muni) %>%`
`filter(pollution$date >= exposition$dt_concep & pollution$date < exposition$data_nasc) %>%`
`mutate(sum = sum(neg_to_7[pollution$date >= exposition$dt_concep & pollution$date < exposition$data_nasc]))`
`}`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV3i4.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qs79.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this Solution: https://softans.com/question/how-can-i-use-another-df-to-calculate-a-new-variable-in-my-df-using-time-intervals/#comment-508

Comment: Please add your data in a way that people can use instead of an image.